# What is the minimal and the characteristic polynomial of T(A) = A^t - A?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the following trasformation:
$$T:M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_n(\mathbb C) \\ T(A) = A^t-A $$
Let $E$ be the standard basis of $M_n(\mathbb C)$. What is the minimal and the characteristic polynomial of $T$?
I tried to solve for $M_2(\mathbb C)$, so the matrix of $T$ is:$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
I'm not sure if this is right and I'll be greatful if you help me to generalize this for $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: What's $T^2(A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every matrix can be decomposed into its symmetric and antisymmetric part:
$$A = A_+ + A_-\quad\text{ where }\quad A_{\pm} = \frac12(A\pm A^T)$$
Notice $T(A_+) = 0$ and $T(A_-) = -2A_-$ and the dimensions for symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
The matrix for $T$ can be diagonalised to one with $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ entries of $0$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ entries of $-2$ on its diagonal. This means

- the minimal polynomial for $T$ is $\lambda(\lambda+2)$
- the characteristic polynomial for $T$ is $\lambda^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(\lambda+2)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

Comment: Why is it that the characteristic polynomial satisfies $ \lambda^{ \dim V_1 } \cdot (\lambda +2 )^{ \dim V_2 } $ ( where $ \dim V_1 $ is dimension of the vector space of symmetric matrices and $ \dim V_2 $ is dimension of the vector space of anti-symmetric matrices) ?

Answer (score 1):

$T^2(A)=T(A^t-A)=(A^t-A)^t-(A^t-A)$ $=A-A^t-A^t+A=-2T(A)$. $X^2+2X$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was easier than I thought :)